# jekyll does not want to work with redcarpet

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, redcarpet

I've installed jekyll and would like to use redcarpet.  My jekyll does not come with this ability from the basic install - so I've tried to install it as a plugin: https://github.com/nono/Jekyll-plugins

It's still not working.  Does anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: That plugin is not required - and jekyll 0.12.0 (current as of this posting) supports redcarpet 2.whatever natively just by saying `markdown: redcarpet` in the `_config.yml` file.  Just get a new version of jekyll and the latest redcarpet and you're fine.